# NameError: name 'test_soft' is not defined. The formula is there, but can't run it

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have this error saying the function is not defined, but there is defined. I don't know why is like that. Have no spaces etc. All those 3 defs are already written in code, but python can't run them. DO you know why.
PLS Those who dont know how to answer, pls dont post any irrelevant answers to this question! Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import cvxopt
import cvxopt.solvers
from numpy import linalg

def linear_kernel (x1,x2):
    return np.dot(x1, x2)

def polynominal_kernel(x,y,p=3):
    return(1+np.dot(x,y))**p
def gaussian_kernel(x, y, sigma=5.0):
    return np.exp(-linalg.norm(x-y)**2 / (2*(sigma**2)))

class SVM(object):

    def  __init__(self, kernel=linear_kernel, C=None):
        self.kernel=kernel
        self.C=C
        if self.C is not None: self.C = float(self.C)

    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features= X.shape

        K=np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
        for i in range(n_samples):
            for j in range (n_samples):
                K[i,j]=self.kernel(X[i], X[j])

        P=cvxopt.matrix(np.outer(y,y)*K)
        q=cvxopt.matrix(np.ones(n_samples)*-1)
        A=cvxopt.matrix(y, (1,n_samples))
        b=cvxopt.matrix(0.0)

        if self.C is None:
            G=cvxopt.matrix(np.diag(np.ones(n_samples)*-1))
            h=cvxopt.matrix(np.diag(np.zeros(n_samples)))
        else:
            tmp1=   np.diag(np.ones(n_samples)*-1)
            tmp2=np.identity(n_samples)
            G=cvxopt.matrix(np.vstack((tmp1,tmp2)))
        solution=cvxopt.solvers.qp(P,q,G,h,A,b) 
        a=np.ravel(solution['x'])

        sv=a>1e-5
        ind=np.arange(len(a)) [sv]
        self.a =a[sv]
        self.sv=X[sv]
        self.sv_y=y[sv]
        print("%d support vectors out of %d points" %(len(self.a), n_samples))

        self.b=0
        for n in range(len(self.a)):
            self.b +=self.sv_y[n]
            self.b -=np.sum(self.a*self.sv_y*K[ind[n],sv])
        self.b /=len(self.a)

        if self.kernel==linear_kernel:
            self.w=np.zeros(n_features)
            for n in range (len(self.a)):
                self.w +=self.a[n]*self.sv_y[n]*self.sv[n]
            else:
                self.w=None
    def project(self,X):
        if self.w is not None:
            return np.dot(X,self.w)+self.b
        else:
            y_predict=np.zeros(len(X))
            for i in range(len(X)):
                s=0
                for a, sv_y, sv in zip(self.a, self.sv_y, self.sv):
                    s +=a*sv_y*self.kernel(X[i], sv)
                y_predict[i]=s
            return y_predict+self.b
    def predict (self,X):
        return np.sign(self.project(X))



if __name__=="main":
    import pylab as pl 

    def gen_lin_separable_data():
        mean1 =np.array([0,2])
        mean2=np.array([2,0])
        cov=np.array([[0.8, 0.6], [0.6, 0.8]])
        X1=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov, 100)
        y1=np.ones(len(X1))
        X2=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov, 100)
        y2=np.ones(len(X2)) * -1
        return X1, y1,X2, y2
    def gen_non_lin_separable_data():
        mean1=[-1,2]
        mean2=[1,-1]
        mean3=[4,-4]
        mean4=[-4,4]
        cov=[[1.0,0.8], [0.8,1.0]]
        X1=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov, 50)
        X1=np.vstack((X1, np.random.multivariate_normal(mean3, cov, 50)))
        y1=np.ones(len(X1))
        X2=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov, 50)
        X2.vstack((X2,np.random.multivariate_normal(mean4, cov, 50)))
        y2=np.ones(len(X2))*-1
        return X1, y1, X2, y2

    def gen_lin_separable_overlap_data():
        mean1 = np.array([0,2])
        mean2=np.array([2,0])
        cov=np.array([1.5, 1.0], [1.0, 1.5])
        X1=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov, 100)
        y1=np.ones(len(X1))
        X2=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov, 50)
        X2.vstack((X2,np.random.multivariate_normal(mean4, cov, 100)))
        y2=np.ones(len(X2))*-1
        return X1, y1, X2, y2
    def split_train(X1, y1, X2, y2):
        X1_train=X1[90:]
        y1_train=y1[:90]
        X2_train=X2[:90]
        y2_train=y2[:90]
        X_train=np.vstack((X1_train, X2_train))
        y_train=np.hstack((y1_train, y2_train))
        return X_train, y_train
    def split_test(X1, y1, X2, y2):
        X1_test=X1[90:]
        y1_test=y1[90:]
        X2_test=X2[90:]
        y2_test=y2[90:]
        X_test=np.vstack((X1_test, X2_test))
        y_test=np.hstack((y1_test, y2_test))
        return X_test, y_test

    def plot_margin(X1_train, X2_train, clf):
        def f(x, w, b, c=0):
            return (-w[0]*x-b+c)/w[1]

        pl.plot(X1_train[:,0], X1_train[:,1], "ro")
        pl.plot(X2_train[:,0], X2_train[:,1], "bo")
        pl.scatter(clf.sv[:,0], clf.sv[:,1], s=100, c="g")

        a0=-4; a1=f(a0, clf.w, clf.b)
        b0=4;b1=f(bo, clf.w, clf.b)
        pl.plot([a0, b0],[a1, b1], "k")

        a0=-4; a1=f(a0, clf.w, clf.b,1)
        b0=4;b1=f(bo, clf.w, clf.b,1)
        pl.plot([a0, b0],[a1, b1], "k--")

        a0=-4; a1=f(a0, clf.w, clf.b,-1)
        b0=4;b1=f(bo, clf.w, clf.b,-1)
        pl.plot([a0, b0],[a1, b1], "k--")

        pl.axis("tight")
        pl.show()

    def plot_contour(X1_train, X2_train, clf):
        pl.plot(X1_train[:,0], X1_train[:,1], "ro")
        pl.plot(X2_train[:,0], X2_train[:,1], "bo")
        pl.scatter(clf.sv[:,0], clf.sv[:,1], s=100, c="g")

        X1, X2 = np.meshgrig(np.linspace(-6, 6, 50), np.linspace(-6,6,50))
        X=np.array([[x1, x2] for x1, x2 in zip(np.ravel(X1), np.ravel(X2))])
        Z=clf.project(X) .reshape(X1.shape)

        pl.contour(X1, X2, Z, [0.0], colors='k', linewidths=1, origin='lower')
        pl.contour(X1, X2, Z+1, [0.0], colors='grey', linewidths=1, origin='lower')
        pl.contour(X1, X2, Z-1, [0.0], colors='grey', linewidths=1, origin='lower')

        pl.axis("tight")
        pl.show
    def test_linear():
        X1, y1, X2, y2=gen_lin_separable_data()
        X_train, y_train=split_train(X1, y1, X2, y2)
        X_test, y_test=split_test(X1, y1, X2, y2)

        clf=SVM()
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

        y_predict=clf.predict(X_test)
        correct=np.sum(y_predict==y_test)
        print("%d out of %d predictions correct" % (correct, len(y_predict)))
        plot_margin(X_train[y_train==1], X_train[y_train==-1], clf)

    def test_non_linear():
        X1, y1, X2, y2=gen_non_lin_separable_data()
        X_train, y_train=split_train(X1, y1, X2, y2)
        X_test, y_test=split_test(X1, y1, X2, y2)

        clf=SVM(polynominal_kernel)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

        y_predict=clf.predict(X_test)
        correct=np.sum(y_predict==y_test)
        print("%d out of %d predictions correct" % (correct, len(y_predict)))
        plot_contour(X_train[y_train==1], X_train[y_train==-1], clf)

    def test_soft():
        X1, y1, X2, y2=gen_lin_separable_overlap_data()
        X_train, y_train=split_train(X1, y1, X2, y2)
        X_test, y_test=split_test(X1, y1, X2, y2)

        clf=SVM(C=1000.1)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

        y_predict=clf.predict(X_test)
        correct=np.sum(y_predict==y_test)
        print("%d out of %d predictions correct" % (correct, len(y_predict)))
        plot_contour(X_train[y_train==1], X_train[y_train==-1], clf)

# test_linear()
# test_non_linear()
# test_soft()

test_soft()
```

Answer (score 0):

My error was: `if __name__=="main":` and should be `if __name__=="__main__":`